# Form submit on same page

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, forms

I want to submit my form on the same page :

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form1" class="ma">
    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>" class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>">
    <?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button>
</form>
```

Form is submitted in cart page so I use `onclick()` function in button but it won't work.

Can anyone please guide me, what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: What is  your objectif to submit the form in the same page, why you dont use `$this->_redirectReferer()` in your controller ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using inline js. Also you should be using Magento js methods to submit the form. I'll see if I can whip up an answer for you.

Comment: You say 'Form is submitted in cart page'. If you are on the cart page, then ```Mage::registry('current_product')``` should return null. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

**You need follow below steps**

- add   **return_url** as a  `new hidden`  input field to from

> `<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $currentUrl
>   =  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />`

- and remove `onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl =
  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>"` for form submit

> `<button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"
>   class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo
>   $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" type="submit">`

**from**

`<button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>" class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>">`

### Update:

Use this it should works:

```
 <form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form1" class="ma">

<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $currentUrl
  =  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />

    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>" class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>" type="submit"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button></form>
```

Comment: Where i have to add form or button. i tried both separately but it redirect to   shopping cart only

Comment: add to cart Working but i used Buy now it should redirect to shopping cart but now it also submit same page it self

Comment: <button class="button buy-now" onClick="location.href ='{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
           <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>